# AFSK clock recovery in noise

Tags: demodulation, fsk

What algorithms are available for optimizing estimated bit clock recovery of an audio FSK modulated signal over an extremely low S/N ratio channel? (e.g. barely audible due to high ambient noise and low max available signal power)

Assume the audio signal is very long in duration and the payload is suitably pseudo-randomly pre-scrambled.  Even if the data cannot be recovered (or perhaps without massive super-redundant FEC), can the clock be recovered accurately?

Comment: Can you provide a quantitative range for "extremely low" SNR? Is the observed clock frequency assumed to be stable over the course of the transmission? Online or offline processing? There are a lot of synchronization methods, with whole books written on the topic.

Comment: @Jason R : Assume stable clock frequencies relative to each other.  Can you recommend good book titles that would cover the topic of this question, or descriptive names of the suitable synchronization methods to google.

Comment: Not good news for your wallet, but [Synchronization Techniques for Digital Receivers](http://www.amazon.com/Synchronization-Techniques-Receivers-Applications-Communications/dp/0306457253/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1345639335&sr=8-2) by Mengali is my favorite. It covers synchronization of all kinds, including frequency, phase, and timing.